# Java Class to JSON custom Schema by Annotation

Tags: java, jackson, annotations, jsonschema

I am currently generating my Json Schema like this:

```
class Item {
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string description;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(Item.class, visitor);
JsonSchema schema = visitor.finalSchema();
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema));
```

Which prints:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "id": "urn:jsonschema:de:foo:bar:User",
    "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "description": { "type": "string" }
    }
}
```

Now I want to append additional information to each type from annotations of the Item class. I want this to provide information for how to display an input for that field.

```
class User {

    public int id;
    public string name;
    @MyJsonSchemaAnnotation(fieldName = "input", value = "textarea")
    public string description;
}
```

Which will give me:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "id": "urn:jsonschema:de:foo:bar:User",
    "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "name": { "type": "string" },
        "description": { "type": "string", "input": "textarea" }
    }
}
```

I think this is similar to @JsonDescription or the JSR 303 Annotations. I'm a bit lost if this is possible at all and if so which way i have to implement it. So if anyone could give me a hint where to look at it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema](https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema) package converts java POJOs to json schema. It has `@JsonPropertyDescription` annotation which could be used to customize schema.

Note that it only supports till draft 4 of json schema, till now.